# What to do when you are invited to another university?

Tags: phd, postdocs

I am currently a Ph.D. student. I was invited for a week by a professor from another university in a second country. He told that he likes me to meet his research team, and to show me what they are working on. This collaboration is intended to be a preparation for a postdoc position in his department.

At the current situation, I do not know what exactly should I show him. I thought of preparing a presentation about my Ph.D. work. Besides, discuss several things.

Also, Is this something that can be written in my CV?

Comment: You have discussed this with your advisor, right? Giving you advice is literally their job.

Comment: Most advisors would want to advise on the *content* of any presentation as well. To some extent you are representing the group/advisor so opportunities for collaboration need to be included, while not giving too much away about work that's just getting started if there's a bit of rivalry.

Comment: An invited talk at another university is worth putting on your CV, certainly in mathematics. These are quite genuine indications of interest in your work.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Since none of the existing answers have included a mention of the advisor, may I recommend turning that comment into an answer?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks David. Sure, I have discussed this with my advisor who said it is a good chance to go there and see your host professor and discuss your future postdoc duties with him. That's only what he said. Therefore, I looked into more answers such as Ian_Fin which is a very good answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Offering to give a presentation about your work sounds like a very good idea. I would suggest contacting the professor as soon as possible saying that you would be keen to present your work. By giving them early notice, you give them the chance to either arrange something for you, or to pass your details onto anybody in the wider department who may run the sorts of seminars/colloquiums where such talks often take place.

In terms of other things you could do, if they've already told you that you'll be introduced to other members of the research team then that sounds like a lot of that will be organised for you. Another thing you may want to consider is to see what other regularly seminars, journal clubs, research groups, etc. already exist that might be of interest to you. If this is somewhere that you may have the opportunity to go and work at then you want to have the fullest sense of what your working environment would be like.

As for putting it on your CV, I'm not entirely sure that a visit is entirely relevant. If it was a visiting job then include it, but something casual like this probably not. It is the sort of thing that may be well worth discussing (if it's relevant) in a cover letter or supporting statement that goes alongside applications.

Answer (score 14):

My CV has a section for talks that I've given at various institutions. You can definitely mention this under such a category.